# z-index not working for flowplayer in firefox

Tags: html, css, flowplayer

I am trying to create a layered div using z-index and one of the layers have to contain a flowplayer. Once layer is created properly I will update div's z-index value based on program's logic. Following code works in Chrome but not in Firefox and IE.

Problem: In IE and firefox div containing flowplayer does not hide.

```
        <div id="dvd_supplement" style="height:200px;width:300px;">
            <!-- this A tag is where your Flowplayer will be placed. it can be anywhere -->
            <div style="z-index:11;position:relative;top:0px;">
                <a id="player"
                     href="barsandtone.flv"
                     style="width:300px;height:200px" 
                    >
                </a>
            </div>
            <div style="z-index:2;position:relative;top:-200px;">
                <img id="player_laptop_screen" src="images/laptop_screen.jpg" width="300px" height="200px"/>                
            </div>
            <div style="z-index:3;position:relative;top:-400px;">
                <img id="player_img" src="images/blank_screen.jpg" width="300px" height="200px"/>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

Comment: I moved your CSS into styles and added a few id's to the `<div>`s just to see what was going on a bit better. Check this fiddle and see if that's working as you expected? http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/2Ts27/

Comment: @davidpauljunior thanks for your response, I have resolved this issue by using an option in flowplayer().                                         flowplayer(
  "player", {src: "../flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", wmode: "opaque"}, {
     clip:  {
      autoPlay: false,
      autoBuffering: true
     }
   }
  );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flowplayer configuration has a `zIndex` attribute

So consider using

```
$f("selector","path-to-your-swf",{
option 1:...,
option 2:...,
option 3:...,
zIndex: value,
...,
...,
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have solved this by using wmode parameter in flowplayer().

Comment: flowplayer(
  "player", {src: "../flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", wmode: "opaque"}, {
     clip:  {
      autoPlay: false,
      autoBuffering: true
     }
   }
  );

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue by using wmode option in flowplayer() i.e.
    flowplayer(
    "player", {src: "../flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", wmode: "opaque"}, {
      clip:  {
          autoPlay: false,
          autoBuffering: true
      }
    }
);